# Error: 'value_type' does not name a type in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a class called Node. Instantiations of Node will form a Doubly-Linked-List of EToll objects. However, I am getting a compiler error inside Node.cpp which states:

"error: ‘value_type’ does not name a type" in line 37, which is:

```
value_type& Node::get_data() const {return data&;}
```

Why is this error happening? And how can I fix it? I'm completely lost, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Node.h code:

```
// Node.h
/*******************************/
// Last Updated: Tues Aug 31
// Program Description: Header file for Node

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "EToll.h"

using namespace std;

class Node {
    
    public:
        typedef EToll value_type; //typedef - now value_type is synonym for EToll object
        
        //Constructors:
        Node(); //default
        Node(const value_type& i, Node* n, Node* p); //specific constructor with 3 arguments. to be implemented in Node.cpp as: i = data item, n = next and p = prev
        
        //Destructor:
        ~Node();
        
        //mutators (setters):
        void set_next(Node*);
        void set_prev(Node*);
        void set_data(const value_type&);
        
        //accessors (getters):
        Node* get_next() const;
        Node* get_prev() const;
        value_type& get_data() const;
        
    private:
        Node* next; //ptr to next (or NULL)
        Node* prev; //ptr to prev (or NULL)
        value_type data; //the payload

};

#endif
```

Node.cpp code:

```
// Node.cpp
/*******************************/
// Last Updated: Tues Aug 31
// Program Description: Implementation of Node

#include "Node.h"
#include <cstdlib>

//Constructors:
Node::Node() //default constructor
{
    data = value_type(); //creates an empty EToll object, since value_type is a synonym for EToll
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}

Node::Node(const value_type& i, Node* n, Node* p)
{
    data = i;
    next = n;
    prev = p;
}

//Empty destructor:
Node::~Node(){}

//Mutators (setters):
void Node::set_next(Node* next_ptr) {next = next_ptr;}
void Node::set_prev(Node* prev_ptr) {prev = prev_ptr;}
void Node::set_data(const value_type& new_data) {data = new_data;}

//Accessors (getters):
Node* Node::get_next() const {return next;}
Node* Node::get_prev() const {return prev;}
value_type& Node::get_data() const {return data;}
```

EToll.h code:

```
// EToll.h
/*******************************/
// Program Description: This is the EToll header

#ifndef ETOLL_H
#define ETOLL_H
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class EToll 
{
public:
    
    // Constructors
    EToll();
    EToll(const string, const string, const double);

    // Destructor
    ~EToll();

    // Setters
    void set_licence(const string);
    void set_type(const string);
    void set_charge(const double);
    void set_all(string licence_, string type_, double charge_);

    // Getters
    string get_licence() const;
    string get_type() const;
    double get_charge() const;

//Private member variables
private:
    string licence; // car's licence plate
    string type;    // type of vehicle
    double charge;  // value of toll
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const EToll&);
bool operator == (const EToll& s1, const EToll& s2);

#endif
```

EToll.cpp code:

```
// EToll.h
/*******************************/
// Program Description: EToll Implementation

#include "EToll.h"
#include <cstdlib>

// Constructors
EToll::EToll()
{
    licence = "";
    type = "";
    charge = 0;
}

EToll::EToll(string licence_, string type_, double charge_)
{
    licence = licence_;
    type = type_;
    charge = charge_;
}

// empty destructor
EToll::~EToll(){}

// Mutator methods (setters)
void EToll::set_licence(const string licence_) {licence = licence_;}
void EToll::set_type(const string type_){ type = type_;}
void EToll::set_charge(const double charge_){ charge = charge_;}
void EToll::set_all(string licence_, string type_, double charge_)
{
    licence = licence_;
    type = type_;
    charge = charge_;
}

// Accessor methods (getters)
string EToll::get_licence() const {return licence;}
string EToll::get_type() const {return type;}
double EToll::get_charge() const {return charge;}

// overloaded stream insertion operator
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const EToll& value)
{
    out << "(" << value.get_licence() << "," << value.get_type() << ") ";
    return out;
}

// overloaded boolean equivalence operator
bool operator == (const EToll& s1, const EToll& s2)
{
    if (s1.get_licence() == s2.get_licence())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: You need `Node::value_type& Node::get_data() const {return data;}`. The return type doesn't check if it is part of a member function, so it doesn't look in `Node` for a `value_type`.

Comment: You have to either make the function return a `const` reference or remove `const` from the member function, otherwise it won't compile. Otherwise, `get_data()` tries to bind a `const EToll` to a `EToll &` which is an error.

Comment: I tried this, and now am getting the compiler error: Node.cpp: In member function ‘Node::value_type& Node::get_data() const’:
Node.cpp:37:50: error: binding reference of type ‘Node::value_type&’ {aka ‘EToll&’} to ‘const value_type’ {aka ‘const EToll’} discards qualifiers (it then highlights the data inside `{return data;}`

Comment: Functions with arguments like `const string licence_` are making copies (because they aren't references) that can't be moved (because they are `const`). Either use `string licence_` and use `std::move` to move the copy (like `licence = `std::move(licence_);`) or make the arguments take `const` reference instead (like `void set_licence(const string &);`.

Comment: That error is solved by my second comment.

Comment: How do I make get_data() return a `const` reference? Sorry if this is a newbie question, I'm new to C++

Comment: ok nevermind I worked it out - just removed const from the `get_data()` function like you said and it works. Thankyou so much man!! Absolute lifesaver bless you